# Weights for model time embeddings have not yet been created

Tags: tensorflow, keras, model

I have an issue in my code. I worked on an diffusion model with a Unet architecture. I would like to save the weights of my model, and I would like to reload these weights.

I did :

```
unet = Unet()

epochs = 4
list_avg = []
for e in range(1, epochs+1):
    # this is cool utility in Tensorflow that will create a nice looking progress bar
    bar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(X_train.shape[0]-1)
    losses = []
    for i, batch in enumerate(iter(X_train)):
        # run the training loop
        loss = train_step(batch)
        losses.append(loss)
        bar.update(i, values=[("loss", loss)])

    avg = np.mean(losses)
    list_avg.append(avg)
    print(f"Average loss for epoch {e}/{epochs}: {avg}")
    ckpt_manager.save(checkpoint_number=e

unet.save_weights('weights')

unet2 = Unet()
unet2.load_weights('weights')
```

My warning :

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGvgM.png)

`unet2.weights`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIdDM.png)